# How can we set Maximum date in Ionic

Tags: datepicker, calendar, ionic4

I am working on ionic app. i installed a componenet ionic-calendar-date-picker. its working fine. Now i have two problems first one is that i want to show dates maximum till 31/December/2018 and other thing is that i have to put back button on that calender. I dont know how to do kindly let me know about this. Or if you have any other component in mind then it would also be helpful. Thanks in advance. My ionic code is as follow

```
<ionic-calendar-date-picker
            [toDate]="calendarMaximum"
            [fromDate]="calendarStart"
            [dayLabelsStyle]=" { 'font-weight': 500, 'font-size': '0.7em' }"
            [itemSelectedStyle]="{'background': '#D31B63', 'color': '#FDBD10', 'border-radius': '25px'}"
            [todaysItemStyle]="{'color':'#D31B63'}"
            (onSelect)="dateClicked($event)"></ionic-calendar-date-picker>
```

and .ts code is as

````
        this.calendarMaximum = moment().subtract(1, 'year').toDate();
        this.calendarStart = moment().subtract(5, 'year').toDate();
        this.getResults(this.dateSelected, true, true);
```[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSnqG.jpg
````

Comment: You already set 'fromDate' and 'toDate'. Users won't be able to select the dates outside of the range. Does it really matter to hide them ? For the second question : What is this back button gonna do ? If you are trying to achive something like fullscreen calendar then put your calendar in a modal. You can add whatever you want to that model including the back button.

Comment: Thanks for your precious response. I have although already set fromdate and todate but user can select date above then this.

Comment: for the other part of question i click on an icon at header of screen it open the calender and when i again click it this close the calendar. my client want a back button on calendar where user should not click the icon on header for closing the calendar. i close it by clicking anywhere on screen but getting problem for this button. its not looking beautiful